# Usando ";" en una consulta que esta en php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la esta consulta:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT Fecha, (@runtot := @runtot + Numero) AS `N`
FROM Tabla
WHERE `ID` = 2
```

Estoy usado esta consulta en una pagina de [php](/questions/tagged/php). Pero como hay una `;` en la consulta (al final de `SET @runtot:=0;`), me falla la consulta cuando lo pruebo en la página de [php](/questions/tagged/php) - en Navicat funciona perfectamente.

¿Qué puedo usar en vez del `;` para poder usarlo en [php](/questions/tagged/php)? o ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la consulta?

Comment: Supongo que debes decir "set delimiter" en algún sitio.

Comment: @fedorqui `SET DELIMITER` no funciona en mysqli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno (finalmente!) lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT t.Fecha, @runtot:=@runtot + t.count AS N
FROM (SELECT Fecha, Numero AS `count`
  FROM Tabla
  WHERE `ID` = 1
  ORDER BY Fecha) t
JOIN (SELECT @runtot := 0 AS dummy) dummy
```